# AdminLTE css doesnt display the header bar after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, adminlte

I'm developing a MVC5 project. But after implementing login, my AlminLTE header and most of the CSS details no longer work.

I removed the "BlockViewHandler" tag in my View's web.config, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: can you share the code as well as current and expected behavior?

Comment: Actually, I think its a configuration issue. Once I redirect to the default page, the CSS doesnt show the full page, just some sketchy menu items. I can share the image if necessary, but its not code related errors.